# How to get an intersect query using CriteriaQuery?

Tags: criteria-api, criteriaquery

Given :

```
@Entity
public class entity_details  {

@Id
private int id;

@column(name ="entity_id")
private int entityId;

@column(name="att_id")
private int attId;

@column(name="att_value")
private string attVal;
```

I want to find a equivalent query to the below one

select entity_id from entity_details where att_id=15 and att_value='test' 
intersect 
select entity_id from entity_details where att_id=18 and att_value='test2';

using CriteriaQuery only.

Answer (score 0):

It is a complex operation, you could try something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);

Root<EntityDetails> root = cq.from(EntityDetails.class);

Subquery<EntityDetails> sq = cq.subquery(EntityDetails.class);
Root<EntityDetails> rootSQ = cq.from(EntityDetails.class);

sq.where(
    cb.and(
        cb.and(
            cb.equal(rootSQ.get("attId"),18),
            cb.equal(rootSQ.get("attValue"),"test2")
        ),
        cb.equal(rootSQ.get("id"),root.get("id"))
    )
);

cq.where(
    cb.and(
        cb.and(
            cb.equal(root.get("attId"),15),
            cb.equal(root.get("attValue"),"test")
        ),
        cb.exist(sq)
    )
);

cq.multiselect(root.get("entityId"));
```

What would generate the following Query:

```
select e1.entity_id from entity_details e1
where e1.att_id = 15 and e1.att_value = "test"
    and exists(
        select * from entity_details e2
        where e2.att_id = 18 and e2.att_value = "test2"
            and e1.id = e2.id
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for take a look into my query. I am really grateful for this solution.